# Prove by induction that $2^{n} < 3^{n}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

PROBLEM:
Prove by induction that:
$$
2^{n} < 3^{n} , \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

ATTEMPT TO PROVE:

1. Let n=1. So, $2^1 = 2$  and  $3^1 = 3$  (Clearly,  $2<3$ )
2. Assume true at $n=k$. So, $2^k < 3^k$
3. Now, let $n=k+1$. (And this is where I get stuck) So,
   $$
   2^{k+1} = 2*2^k < 2*3^k = ?
   $$
   I know that I need to manipulate $2*3^k$ so that I end up with $3^{k+1}$
   I was thinking I could do the following, but I don't know if it makes sense:
   $$
   2^{k+1} = 2*2^k < 2*3^k
   $$
   $$
   2*3^k = 6^k
   $$
   $$
   6^k = (3+3)^k
   $$
   $$
   (3+3)^k = 3^k + 3^k
   $$
   $$
   3^k + 3^k = 3^{k+1}
   $$

Comment: Cameron Williams has the correct way to proceed from where you got stuck.  But it's worth noting that several of your steps after "I don't know if it makes sense" are incorrect.  In particular $$2\cdot 3^k \ne 6^k \\ (3+3)^k \ne 3^k+3^k \\ 3^k+3^k\ne3^{k+1}$$

Answer (score 5):

What you have written is not correct. The way to proceed might be so simple that it's completely eluding you. This happens to all of us. You know that $2 < 3$, so $2\cdot 3^k < 3\cdot 3^k$.

Comment: Just to be picky (which is arguably justified by the nature of the problem), you are assuming here that $3^k$ is *positive*.

Comment: Fair enough! $\, $

Answer (score 0):

Some general notes – you should always start with a proposition because it becomes unclear with harder induction problems what exactly you're trying to prove. Say $P(n) = 2^n < 3^n$.

Your base case is correct, so I will expand on the inductive step. You need to prove $P(n + 1)$ or $2^{n +1} < 3^{n + 1}$.

1. Assume $P(n)$ or $2^n < 3^n$
2. $2 \cdot 2^n < 2 \cdot 3^n$ (by the inductive hypothesis)
3. $2 \cdot 3^n < 3 \cdot 3^n$, so $2 \cdot 2^n < 3 \cdot 3^n$
4. $2 \cdot 2^n = 2^{n + 1}$ and $3 \cdot 3^{n} = 3^{n + 1}$, so $2^{n + 1} = 3^{n + 1}$